# How to get link of youtube videos on click in WebView of Android Studio?

Tags: android, webview

I am building an app and the webview loads youtube.
I want that when someone clicks on a video, it displays a toast containing the link which is clicked.

I have tried using shouldOverrideUrlLoading and it works when clicked on on any url but not on youtube.

What can the issue be ? Should i use javascript ?

Any help is appreciated.

The code i used follows -

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    WebView mywebview = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
    WebSettings webSettings = mywebview.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mywebview.loadUrl("https://www.youtube.com");
    mywebview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()

    {

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

            try {

                // do whatever you want to do on a web link click
               String hello = url;

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,hello,
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return false;
        }


    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I sorted this up with using Advanced Web View
https://github.com/delight-im/Android-AdvancedWebView

and calling webview.getOriginalUrl() on button click so when the page loads and you click the button, it displays a toast containing the link.

Comment: how do i intercept the button click from youtube search page?

Comment: where I should use webview.getOrinigalURL() and onActivityResult not called.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
player.getVideoUrl():String
```

Returns the YouTube.com URL for the currently loaded/playing video.

```
player.getVideoEmbedCode():String
```

Returns the embed code for the currently loaded/playing video. More information can be found [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Retrieving_video_information).

Comment: That should be used as a javascript right ? If it won't be a trouble, give me an example please.